# Simple Class Error in Python from Guidebook

Tags: python

I am literally copying the guidebook word for word. I am putting in this code:
butt:

```
class Dog():

    def _init_(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting")
    def roll_over(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " rolled over")

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
my_dog.sit()
my_dog.roll_over()
```

However, instead of getting : "willie has rolled over" I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dog.py", line 10, in <module>
    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Please help me.... I want to know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: `__init__` needs two underscores on either side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double underscore instead of single underscore.
define the method with `__init__` instead of `_init_`.

That will solve.

Because `__init__` builds your `Dog` class's object, whereas `_init_` doesn't.
As stated in the [python-docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) `__init__` is called when the instance is created

Answer (score 0):

change `_init_` to `__init__` then your code would compile just fine. read more about `__init__` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)